# Tile server performance seemling inconsistant with SSH Launch vs 'Local' Launch

Tags: server, ssh, python, performance

I am setting up a Dell PowerEdge R410 as a tile server (i.e. a server which serves web map images á la Google Maps) and experimenting with TileStache -- a Python application which handles HTTP requests, requests the tiles from the rendering software (Mapnik) and manages the caching of served tiles.

The strange thing is, if I SSH into the server and run `tilestache-server.sh -i 192.168.1.28` it works superbly. However, if I run the exact same command with a keyboard plugged into the server instead of over SSH each tile on my web map takes seconds to load.

I have posted [an issue](https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache/issues/253) on the project GitHub page but the fact it is the same command would suggest it is something environmental... any ideas what it might be?  May the kernel handle threading differently for some reason if an command is executed over SSH?

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04.